# How to get a list of strings for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I obtain after doing certain operations. This is how my dataframe looks like

```
        date metric  stat         val       device
0 2018-03-21    cpu  mean   76.724406  10.41.100.1
3 2018-03-21    cpu   std  124.285789  10.41.100.1
```

Now I want to convert it to a list of strings stored inside a list, something like below

```
lis = [["2018-03-21", "cpu", "mean", "76.724406", "10.41.100.1"],
["2018-03-21", "cpu", "mean", "124.285789", "10.41.100.1"]]
```

I did something like this

```
for i in df:
    print(df[i].tolist())
```

But I get something like this

```
[Timestamp('2018-03-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-21 00:00:00')]
['cpu', 'cpu']
['mean', 'std']
[76.72440613174048, 124.28578926665278]
['10.41.100.1', '10.41.100.1']
```

But I want the format to be like mentioned above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for `string`s first, then convert `DataFrame` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and last for `list` call [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
lis = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
print (lis)
[['2018-03-21', 'cpu', 'mean', '76.724406', '10.41.100.1'], 
 ['2018-03-21', 'cpu', 'std', '124.285789', '10.41.100.1']]
```

Comment: @SouvikRay - First I dont read question carefully :) Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978732/9209546) by jezrael works.

However, I would suggest you take advantage of the `numpy` representation directly, since this is a more efficient way of storing and manipulating data.

It is rarely the case that a list is *more useful* than the `numpy` representation when dealing with structured data.

You can do this via:

```
res = df.values.astype(str)
```

This returns dtype `<U11`, while `df.astype(str).values` returns dtype `Object`. This is a significant difference in how the data is stored internally.